# How to add download link to html, where href is a .mp4 that is hosted online?

Tags: html, cloudinary

I want to allow a user to download a .mp4 file that is hosted on Cloudinary. I currently have this:

```
   <a
   target="__blank"
   href='https://res.cloudinary.com/dental- 
   intelligence/video/upload/v1576364994/ippevbecmsljhzkfklyi.mp4'
   download
   >
   Download
   </a>
```

but all it does is open the url and begin playing the video. Is there a way to download it directly to the user's computer once they press download?

Comment: I believe there is a `download` attribute. Don't quote me on that

Comment: the download attribute is present in my example.

Comment: okay, so we've learned two things. a) the `download` attribute doesn't work and b) I need glasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove the target attribute and use the `attachment` flag in Cloudinary (`fl_attachment`).

```
<a href='https://res.cloudinary.com/dental-intelligence/video/upload/fl_attachment/ippevbecmsljhzkfklyi.mp4'>Download</a>
```

Comment: awesome. that works. is there a way to add that to every file i host there?

Comment: Sure, if you're using any of the Cloudinary SDKs then you can use the 'url' (for images) and 'video_url` helper methods to build your URLs and pass that option there. All URLs generated via this method will then have this flag. For example, using the JS SDK you can use the 'video_url' method, pass the public_id (ippevbecmsljhzkfklyi.mp4) in your example and the flag transformation. In addition, you can configure a custom name for the downloaded file. Here's a short JSFiddle with that example - https://jsfiddle.net/kv1dy9fw/.

Comment: You are a lifesaver my friend